# How to handle errors in for await

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I have this node/mongodb app with this function:

```
const myFuncDoesALotOfThings = async () => {
    try{
        await CollectionA.deleteMany({});
        await CollectionB.deleteMany({});
        const allCollectionsC = CollectionsC.find({'country': "UK"});   
        for await (const coll of allCollectionsC){
            if(coll.city === 'London'){
                await doSomeMongoDbOperation(); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch(exception){
        console.log("exception",exception);
        //here I think I want to resume
    }
}
```

My concern is about the failure of `await doSomeMongoDbOperation();`.
How can I make sure that exception on one single `await doSomeMongoDbOperation();` will not stop the iteration?

Comment: Use a `try`/`catch` *where the exception is* and *where you want to resume*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap another try catch around your api so it won't stop the iteration.

```
const myFuncDoesALotOfThings = async () => {
    try{
        await CollectionA.deleteMany({});
        await CollectionB.deleteMany({});
        const allCollectionsC = CollectionsC.find({'country': "UK"});   
        for await (const coll of allCollectionsC){
            if(coll.city === 'London'){
              try{
                await doSomeMongoDbOperation(); 
                } catch(e){
                   console.log("mongo operation failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(exception){
        console.log("exception",exception);
        //here I think I want to resume
    }
}
```